# Why does the following code output only one of the oldest and youngest person in a personnel database but not both?

Tags: c

Given a personnel database in an array of structs, the following code should scan for the oldest and youngest person and output both.
However, dependent on the order of the input (first the oldest or first the youngest) it outputs either only the youngest person or the oldest person.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct personal_matter_tag{
    char name[10];
    int age;
}personal_matter_t;

personal_matter_t personnel[3];

int main(){
    int min,max,n;

    for(n=0;n<2;n++){
        printf("Person name:\n");
        scanf("%s",&personnel[n].name);
        printf("Person age:");
        scanf("%d",&personnel[n].age);
    }

    for (n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
      max = personnel[0].age;
      if (max < personnel[n].age) printf("%s is older\n", personnel[n].name);
    }

    for (n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
      min = personnel[0].age;
      if (min > personnel[n].age) printf("%s is younger\n", personnel[n].name);
    }
}
```

Can you help me in finding the bug which results in the missing output?

Comment: `did i missed something in my program` yes indentation.

Comment: `for (n=0; n<2; n++)` loops twice: first with `n=0`, and second with `n=1`. It never gets to loop with `n=2`.

Comment: Probably you come up with the solution yourself if you cleanup your code a bit according to indentation, line separation and more meaningful variable naming. Use english naming.

Comment: @pqans: The policy of Stack Overflow is that only the **asker** may edit **logic** and **naming** used in his/her code. Others may only fix code **formatting** and **comments** in the code. See [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) on meta for more info. It seems not all reviewers are familiar with this policy; only this could explain why your edit has been approved.

Comment: I would be willing to restore the original naming. The logic has not changed, though. Still this question is closed, so hoping that this has'nt caused too much hazzle. What about the reformulated question text?

Answer (score 1):

> why it shows only 1 kid instead of 2 kids

you probably mean why only 2 kids are enter rather than 3, this is because of your `for` conditions being `n<2` rather than `n<=2` or better `n < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)`

But you have additional problems in your code

> ```
> scanf("%s", &a[n].nume);
> ```

must be

```
scanf("%s", a[n].nume);
```

or

```
scanf("%s", &a[n].nume[0]);
```

but it is also dangerous to not limit the size of the read string because if the input name is too long you will write out of the array, at minimum do for instance :

```
scanf("%9s", a[n].nume);
```

Your way to get the min and max age is wrong because you always compare with the very first kid, can be

```
 int max_rank = 0;
 int min_rank = 0;

 for (n = 1; n<sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); n++) {
   if (a[max_rank].anul < a[n].anul) 
     max_rank = n;
   if (a[min_rank].anul > a[n].anul)
     min_rank = n;
 }
 printf("%s is older\n", a[max_rank].nume);
 printf("%s is younger\n", a[min_rank].nume);
```

You also do not check your `scanf`success because you do not check the return value, this is dangerous and you can use not initialized values because of that.

May be also check the read ages are not negative to refuse them ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct copii {
  char nume[10]; 
  int anul;
}a[3];

int main(){
  int n;

  for(n=0; n < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); n++){
    printf("Kid's name:\n");
    if (scanf("%9s", a[n].nume) != 1) {
      puts("EOF, abort");
      return -1;
    }
    printf("Kid's year:");
    if ((scanf("%d",&a[n].anul) != 1) || (a[n].anul < 0)) {
      puts("invalid age, abort");
      return -1;
    }
  }

  int max_rank = 0;
  int min_rank = 0;

  for (n = 1; n<sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); n++) {
    if (a[max_rank].anul < a[n].anul) 
      max_rank = n;
    if (a[min_rank].anul > a[n].anul)
      min_rank = n;
  }

  printf("%s is older (%d)\n", a[max_rank].nume, a[max_rank].anul);
  printf("%s is younger (%d)\n", a[min_rank].nume, a[min_rank].anul);  

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall c.c
/tmp % ./a.out
Kid's name:
k1
Kid's year:50
Kid's name:
k2
Kid's year:10
Kid's name:
k3
Kid's year:12
k1 is older (50)
k2 is younger (10)
/tmp %
```

Comment: This answer guesses what the author of the question could have been meant. It does not answer the question. It adds some remarks to sane usage of scanf by good will. However it is a little bit out of the scope to the question. Additionally there is an obvious error in the answer which suggests to update `max_rank`/`min_rank` when `max`/`min` satisfy a certain condition. It does not suggest to update `max`/`min`, either. I doubt the answer has been checked before posting it here.

Comment: @pqans you are fully right, even you do not have to speak about reputation because whatever it.I edited my answer, For my defense when I answered I was in very bad condition to enter it and very far about to test it too, try yourself to reply on a phone and you will understand ^^ Thank you for warning me

Comment: The newest edit addresses what i complained about this answer in my previous comments and the answer is correct, now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not the for condition. The check `n<2` implies looping over indices 0 and 1, which are indeed two runs. The question was why it shows only 1 kid instead of two and the question was not why it shows only 2 kids instead of 3. Nor is it the syntax of the scanf (The & is not necessary but it is not wrong)

The problem is the that max and min variables are not updated within the for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct copii{
    char nume[10]; 
    int anul;
}a[3];

int main(){
    int min,max,n;
    for(n=0;n<2;n++){
        printf("Kid's name:\n");
        scanf("%s",&a[n].nume);
        printf("Kid's year:");
        scanf("%d",&a[n].anul);
    }

    max=a[0].anul;
    for(n=0;n<2;n++){
        if(max<a[n].anul) max = a[n].anul;
    }
    printf("The oldest kid is %d years old\n", max );

    min=a[0].anul;
    for(n=0;n<2;n++){
        if(min>a[n].anul) min = a[n].anul;
    }
    printf("The youngest kid is %d years old\n", min);
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: oh you also put an answer, your DV is not from me, so I can only suppose some reasons : one entry of the array is unused, you initialize min and max with the entry 0 so to start the two loops with the index 0 (rather than 1) is 'poor', and considering only 2 kids it is useless to do loops in fact

Comment: may be also you print the min/max age but OP wanted to print the corresponding names and your code does not allows to print them. Good continuation and happy coding